# com.android.tools.build:gradle 3.0.0 and platformBuildVersionName

Tags: android, gradle, airwatch

I have been investigating an issue with `platformBuildVersionName` and `platformBuildVersionCode` not present in `AndroidManifest` that is embedded into output .apk file. From what I have found when using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3` those fields are in the output manifest but when switching to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` they are gone.

`platformBuildVersionName` and `platformBuildVersionCode` fields seem to be very vaguely documented, most things that I could find were user questions, not official documentation. It seems that in general I shouldn't care if those fields exist or not at all. They didn't bother me until today actually.

I am stuck with this problem as AirWatch is using those fields for something and it seems crucial for them. My guess here is not to use undocumented stuff like that in your software but I'm not in the position to tell them that.

Anyone had experience with those fields added during apk build time with Gradle 3.0.0?

Comment: here is a link to a similar issue but no clue regarding the platformVersion... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166760/gradle-upgrade-4-1-doesnt-load-versioncode-and-versionname/48326188#48326188

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same issue with AirWatch!  From an open support ticket with AirWatch, they say the following:

*We found a feature request associated with this behavior and the gradle build version.
The reference ID is PR-195117. 
There are 2 workarounds.
1. Build the apk using the gradle plugin 2.3.3 
2. Upload the apk built using gradle plugin 3.x as a separate app on the console. Define App/ID version code manually and deploy.*

They recommend downgrading to gradle 2.3.3

I tried to manually add those attributes to the AndroidManifest.xml file.   Was able to add them to the built apk, but AirWatch still wasn't happy.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Been there, done that too. Solution with redeploying the app each time results in not being able to upgrade the app with new version. Another redeployment is needed. No go for my case. We ended up using Gradle 2.3.3 to build the app as it was crucial to be able to update the app and not wait for AirWatch to implement their fix.